# Issues loading files from within css files

Tags: css

i just started using craft on a local domain and i have some issues.
my stylesheet(a few files) are loaded using html`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">`, and it works great for css and js files, but files requested from within the css aren't loading.
for example the Font Awesome @fontface.

Any ideas? and the is any issue using html instead of the {{ getHeadHtml() }} method?

Thanks Ahead!

Comment: Have you tried using root relative paths?  `/style/style.css` instead of `style/style.css`?

Comment: yes, iv'e tried

Comment: How about in the CSS file itself?  What do your `selector: url(path);` look like?

Comment: its relarive: url(url/to/some/path);

Comment: https://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/

Answer (score 1):

For static assets I usually use something like this:

```
{% if craft.debugMode %}
    {% set assetsUrl = siteUrl %}
{% else %}
    {% set assetsUrl = "assets.mysite.com" %}
{% endif %}
```

And then I can set assets URL's the same way as navigation URLs. ie.

```
{% includeJsFile assetsUrl ~ "js/init.js" %}

{% includecss %}
body.landing #page-wrapper {
    background-image: url(" {{ assetsUrl }}img/pic01.jpg  }}");

}
{% endincludecss %}
```